# How to print this bracket?

Tags: math-mode, symbols, brackets

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How to look up a math symbol?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-math-symbol)
>   [A symbol for the field of formal Laurent series](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4616/a-symbol-for-the-field-of-formal-laurent-series)

[image]

Could anyone tell me how to print the left bracket in these 2 formulae? And their corresponding right one (not ')').

Comment: Please crop your image to an acceptable size.

Comment: Give [Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) a go: Just draw the symbol there, and look at the suggested symbols. I think it's `\llparenthesis` from the `stmaryrd` package.

Comment: I don't think this should be downvoted. The question itself is fine and relevant to other people. Just because it might be a duplicate, that doesn't mean it's a bad question. Plus, it includes an image, which is much better than just describing the character.

Comment: @Jake: I downvoted because of how careless the question was done with that huge image. The question is still far from ideal, but better now.

Comment: that's nood a reason to downvote ...

Comment: I'm glad to see that both possible duplicates got shown (the score was 2-2 when I voted).

Comment: @Herbert: I'd say that questions that show that the OP hasn't done any work himself are the only reasons to downvote (off-topic/duplicate/non-constructive should simply be closed). I'm slowly coming to the conclusion that some downvoting might be helpful to show users not to abuse the system and let other people do all the work for them. (But this discussion should be done on Meta, and not in comments to some random question.)