# How to define a symbol using its unicode number?

Tags: unicode-math, delimiters

I want to define a pair of delimiters that look like (( and )). According to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4616/a-symbol-for-the-field-of-formal-laurent-series/4635#4635), I am looking for `U+2E28` and `U+2E29`. However, I have no idea how to use these to define the symbols I want. What I have tried:

```
\usepackage{stickstootext}
\usepackage[stix2,vvarbb]{newtxmath}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\lParen}{\mathopen}{boldsymbols}{"2E28}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\rParen}{\mathclose}{boldsymbols}{"2E29}
```

But what shows are strange symbols rather than I expect.

**P.S.** You can try `$\Big\lParen bla \Big\rParen$` to see why I do not want to simply define

```
\newcommand\lParen{\mathopen{(\!(}}
\newcommand\lParen{\mathclose{)\!)}}
```

Answer (score 2):

To appear, and in particular to grow with `\Big`, the font needs to define the character, including a recipe for providing size variants.
U+2E28 is in the `Supplemental Punctuation` block of unusual text punctuation, it is not in any of the opentype math fonts that I tried

You might be able to use U+2985 U+2986

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Stix Two Math}
%\setmathfont{Cambria Math}
\begin{document}
$⦅x⦆ \Biggl⦅x\Biggr⦆$
\end{document}
```

[image]