# Resizable delimiters with StixTwo OTF without unicode-math

Tags: xetex, unicode, delimiters, resize, stix2

What exactly is involved with setting up delimiters with XeTeX, Unicode, and OpenType fonts?  I found this answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/692859/224317 which looks promising.  I have also looked at `\Udelcode`, `\Udelcodenum`, and `\Udelimiter`, but cannot seem to find an example of how to set these up.  I am *not* using `unicode-math` because I am using `mtpro2`.  Is the "recipe" for resizing part of the font or is `unicode-math` required?  `StixTwoMath-Regular.otf` has a number of nice delimiters.  I was surprised that the double-parentheses (crescents) are resizable, so this gives me hope, but examples are scarce or nonexistent.

Comment: this is question 1001 how to use something provided by unicode-math. Are you really sure it's not simpler to use unicode-math and just adjust to load mtpro2 in addition?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I cannot answer that question as knowledgeably as I would like.  `mtpro2.sty` attempts to redefine a great many commands and going about it this way seemed like the lesser of two evils.  Plus, I want to have more than one of each type of character set available at once (a double struck and a sans blackboard, for example) and I suspect that I would still need to do some of this add-on coding even if I somehow managed to do as you say.  And once I get this fully functioning, I will not have to worry about it in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you must...

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

% luatex \font\x="StixTwoMath:mode=base;script=math;language=dflt;"
\font\x="[STIXTwoMath-Regular]"

\newfam\stx
\textfont\stx=\x
\Umathcode"2985 4 \stx "2985
\Umathcode"2986 5 \stx "2986
\Udelcode"2985 \stx "2985
\Udelcode"2986 \stx "2986

\begin{document}
$⦅x⦆ \Biggl⦅x\Biggr⦆$
\end{document}
```